# how to check if a value of a boolean in firebase is true or false

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm making a website and since im new to JS, I found a web tutorial online. I wrote the code, but even if my seller value (boolean) is true, it just doesn't pass the if condition... There isn't any problem in css or html.. Im using cloud firestore to store user profiles like username and pwd and stuff. I have attached the js code below. If you want another file, just reply below! Thanks!

```js
const productListingElement = document.querySelector('.product-listing')
const nopeElement = document.querySelector('.become-seller')

window.onload = () => {
    if(sessionStorage.user){
        let user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.user);
        if(compareToken(user.authToken, user.email)){
            if(!user.seller){
                nopeElement.classList.remove('hide');
            } else{
                productListingElement.classList.remove('hide');
            }
        } else{
            location.replace('/login')
        }
    } else{
        location.replace('/login')
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(!user.seller)` is checking if the user is NOT a seller. Is that what you want? Otherwise, remove the `!`.

Comment: Yes, I want to check if the user is a seller or not... But even if the user is a seller, the else condition is not executing... Only the if condition is executing...